# Failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Error:

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'Entities.Customer' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

My code:

```
public bool Update(TEntity entity)
{
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            EntitySet.Attach(entity);

            Context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return result;
}
```

This way I worked, I do not know because it no longer works

Comment: You show a tiny fragment of your code. It's not clear where `EntitySet` is initialized or what it's lifetime is. This error usually indicates that a context's lifespan is too long.

Comment: If you really want an answer you'll have to put more effort in giving meaningful feedback on comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try get entity from db or local context and then update it. Do it, for example, in your catch block.
Example of catch block in that case:

```
catch
{
    // get entity here
    // for example Context.Set<TEntity().Local.FirstOrDefault(selector); 
    //or .Find() instead of .FirstOrDefault()
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with using block:

```
try
{
    /* For avoiding "Attaching an entity of type 'Xxxxx' failed because another entity of 
    the same type already has the same primary key value." error use this method like this */
    using (var context = new Context.Entry<TEntity>())
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; // modified
        context.SaveChanges(); //Must be in using block
        result = true;
    }
}
```